# System unity crashed in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: unity, firefox, thunderbird, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and many systems connected to the network, all  system has the same problem.

Firefox and Thunderbird are not working and not showing Desktop. Unity automatically crashed and not working properly...so please tell me how I am solved this problem.?

Suddenly this problem come in my all network system.
I am using following command but still problem not solved:-

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

and reset Unity.

Answer (score 0):

**Type the following in  Terminal:**

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now reboot and you should have the Unity desktop environment installed.

if it shows and dependency problem or error try these steps:

```
    sudo apt-get check
    sudo apt-get install -f
```

It should repair all problems with dependencies or errors